# 'a' or 'an', in this case?

Tags: word-usage, punctuation

The sentence is the following:

> This is a (apparently) beautiful town.

Should it be 'an' because of the Parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

Ir should be **an** because it's followed by a non-consonant sound "*a*" in "*apparently*".

> This is **an** (apparently) beautiful town.
>   This is **a** beautiful town.